# WP8 handling null recieved through databinding as some other value/nice value

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, windows-phone-8

### Problem Description

Some time ago when I was learning about databinding in **Windows Phone 8** I was reading a tutorial related to it.

**In this tutorial, the tutor explained, how to mask that the value you have recieved was null and show something else instead. I know it was fairly easy, but I was busy with the basics so I just browsed through.**

But now, when I got to solving this problem I can't remember where the tutorial was and can't find it, nor do I know how to name it so I can ask.

What I remember was that he wrote something more to the binding definition in XAML or around it, specyfying how should the value look like when there is null.

**Does it strike a bell for someone, who can tell me what is the name of the thing i want to ask about or show me the link to the tutorial or explain how to do it if you know?**

P.S.: Basically I would like to know how to put something else as value, when valkue recieved through binding is `null` or how to show it nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're searching for is [`TargetNullValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeProperty, TargetNullValue='Empty'}" />
```

Comment: @mishan don't forget to mark the mans answer correct since the question was answered. :)

Comment: Srry, got my head stuck at work and forgot everything else. :)